# Microsoft disk integrity tools like ScanDisk, CheckDisk, and Error-Checking? How do they differ?

Tags: windows, disk-utility, maintenance, check-disk, scan-disk

There's been something I've been curious about regarding 'disk integrity' tools for sometime now...

Specifically, as regards computers that use an operating-system by Microsoft, there's been 4 tools that come bundled with the corresponding operating-system which are related to 'disk integrity'.

They are:
a) MS Scandisk
b) MS Check Disk
c) MS chkdsk
d) MS Windows Error Checking

**(1)** What are the diffrences between the 4 listed above?

**(2)** Are any of these tools considered 'successors' or 'predecessors' of any of the other tools? Or, for that matter are any of the 4names above simply a 're-naming' of one of the other tools?

**(3)** if any of these tools are available on windows 7, are:
a) their functions merged into one tool, thus replacing various tools used on previous versions of windows?
b) are they available on Windows 7 as separate tools?

I know the wording of these questions are a little bit tricky to grasp, but believe me, I was struggling to try to find a better way to word them.

Thanks for the info in advance!

---

---

---

**EDITS AND UPDATES**

Based on the comments that I've read below, the following statements are true:

`

**(1)** What I termed as 'MS Check Disk' and 'MS chkdsk' are the same thing (which is what I suspected).

**(2)** What I had termed as 'disk integrity tools' or simply as 'tools' in my Question, ought be properly called, **'disk checking tools'**.

**(3)** Years ago, for systems that used DOS as the operating-system, the only disk checking tool around was chkdsk.

**(4)** Likewise, fewer years ago, when there was an *actual* operating-system called WindowsNT, the only disk checking tool that came bundled was chkdsk.

**(5)** For Windows9x systems (i.e., Windows 95, Windows 98, and Windows ME), Microsoft bundled a disk checking tool called ScanDisk. ScanDisk was essentially the same thing as chkdsk, but it featured a GUI.

**(6)** Windows9x systems bundled a disk checking tool called ScanDisk, but they also bundled the traditional chkdsk disk checking tool which was ran from the DOS/CMD-prompt.

**(7)** Subsequent operating-systems by Microsoft -- namely, Windows2000, WindowsXP, WindowsVista, Windows7 -- do not include a disk checking tool called ScanDisk.

**(8)** These same subsequent operating-systems by Microsoft -- namely, Windows2000, WindowsXP, WindowsVista, Windows7 -- do, however, include a disk checking tool that is very simply named, "Error Checking" which is accessed via the "Properties Dialog Window" for the corresponding disk.

**(9)** The "Error Checking" disk checking tool is a GUI version of chkdsk.

**(10)** Subsequent operating-systems by Microsoft -- namely, Windows2000, WindowsXP, WindowsVista, Windows7 -- do feature a GUI version of chkdsk called "Error Checking", but they also bundled the traditional chkdsk disk checking tool which was ran from the DOS/CMD-prompt.

`

Can you please tell me if the statements above are true?

No need to *correct* any of the statements that are not true-- on account of the fact that doing so would require excessively lengthy responses. Instead, please just tell me which of the statements are not true.

*I apologize for the verbosity. But, because I'm trying to clarify general computing concepts and vocabulary, the verbosity seemed warranted.*

Thanks in advance, not just for an answer, but also for putting up with the verbosity

Comment: Check Disk and chkdsk are the same program. Scandisk got renamed to chkdsk in Windows XP.

These are all the same program.

Comment: Concerning your edits: as far as I can tell, you got it all correctly.

Answer (score 2):

There are actually two different programs called [`chkdsk`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK): one for DOS and one for NT systems. They both share similar command-line interface, although `chkdsk` for NT is ovbiously more powerful (NTFS support, bad block scanning).

In order to provide bad block scanning functions and a nice GUI for DOS/Win9x, Microsoft created [ScanDisk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ScanDisk). Win9x version was implemented as a rare "double executable", containing a mix of 16 and 32-bit code. When run in 32-bit enviromnent it would use [window-based interface](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Cc767125.f16-08x_big%28en-us,TechNet.10%29.gif), while in DOS it would use a [text-based UI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_ScanDisk#/media/File:Microsoft_Scandisk_%28Windows_98%29.png).

When Windows 2000 and XP were released, ScanDisk was removed from the OS. All you have since then is `chkdsk` for NT systems, which can be called via [command line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CHKDSK#/media/File:Chkdsk_screenshot.png) or using [disk properties dialog](http://www.7tutorials.com/files/img/check_disk/chkdsk2.png)

Answer (score 1):

The four were same and they were not merged

The Ms Scan disk & Ms check disk and Ms error checking were just terminologies and they were **various terms of disk checking** ,

`Scandisk` was a separate command before xp and now only `chkdsk` is available for disk error check

From [ehow](https://itstillworks.com/difference-between-chkdsk-scandisk-7373169.html) :

> Scandisk Scandisk has gradually been phased out of computers and has
> been replaced by Chkdsk. Scandisk was designed to scan the computer's
> hard drive for possible errors or problems. It was not included with
> any Windows versions after XP.
>
> Chkdsk Chkdsk is designed to check a computer's hard drive and make
> sure it is functioning properly. It is a relatively simple program
> that runs in a small black DOS box within the Windows interface